# What does it mean when 25th percentile, median and 75th percentile are the exact same value?

Tags: distributions, boxplot

I am trying to study the distribution of a variable, tax rate. When I calculate some stats and make some plots, I notice that the 25th, median, and 75th percentile are the exact same value.

```
count    1155.000000
mean        0.583411
std        13.671535
min         0.000000
25%         0.010000
50%         0.010000
75%         0.010000
max       328.700000
```

How do we interpret the distribution? Do we say that 25% of values are below 0.01 and 75% above. Most of the values are centered / clustered around 0.01.

Comment: It means more than 50% of your values are exactly "0.01" (probably a lot more, but we can't easily say). Is that some kind of detection threshold? ... Id suggest taking a more detailed look at the distribution.

Comment: @Glen_b I was rounding the values to 2 decimals and losing precision. My distribution now looks more reasonable.